# Store other languages in SQL Server 2008 and retrieve back

Tags: c#, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using an Excel sheet to upload my records into a database. Some columns in the Excel sheet are not in English language. How can I read and store the other language into the database?

I can perfectly read and store English in database. I searched google for some options. I tried the following code to convert it to `UTF8` and store in database. I database I am using `nvarchar(MAX)` .

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dsExcel.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString());
string myString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

When it gets stored in database I can see only `??????????` in the column. If I take input from a textbox and store then I don't have any problem.

Please help - what can be done?

I want to store and retrieve the same language string from the database.

Comment: There is no need to convert to UTF-8 only to convert it back in the next line

Comment: @Alejandro : PLease can you elaborate.? what data type i should take in database. PLus when i read from excel, I see blocks instead of the string.

Comment: I don't think you should manually encode your strings. Just save to database "as is". And yes, nvarchar is the right choice of datatype to store unicode symbols.

Comment: You need to show us how you're **inserting** those values into your SQL Server table!

Comment: `string` data type is fine, it's the standard way .NET treats texts, and it deals with its encoding internally. In your first line you call a `ToString()`, which converts the result of the Excel sheet cell into a .NET string, and in addition all ado objects using to deal with databases also receive strings, so you're already fine. Conversion to UTF-8 just to convert it back to string in the next line achieves nothing really.

Comment: `PLus when i read from excel, I see blocks instead of the string` That's the real problem, the data is coming corrupted already, so anything you do afterwards isn't going to have a good result. The DB thing is most likely irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is probably the UTF8 encoding you are using. You need to use Unicode.

But it seems unnecessary to use the Encoding type: why not just get the string from the DataTable row? By default the CLR treats strings as unicode.

```
string myString = dsExcel.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString();
```

Comment: [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) **IS** unicode, it's one possible encoding to represent unicode characters as bytes the computer can handle.

Comment: It is Unicode, yes, but UTF-8 is unicode **represented** by a limited character set. The question demands something else: the task is to store characters in their UTF-16 format, which can encode the full Unicode character set. The System.String type in .Net is UTF-16, which is the same as SQL Server's nvarchar data type.

Comment: Not really, UTF-8 just uses a different byte enconding, but of course, like all unicode encodings, it supports the whole set of characters. The problem don't appears to be related with the encoding in .NET, but on how Excels sends data to the program, it appears to be a mismatch there.